# How to generate a dataframe from the results of a concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, concurrent.futures, process-pool

**My Goal**

Rewriting a loop (synchronous) using multiprocessing to reduce calculation time (it is looping over millions of rows):

```
def get_info(uid):
    res = requests.get(CallURL+uid, 
                       headers={'Content-Type':'application/json',
                                'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(tokn)})
    foundation_date =  json.loads(res.text).get('uniteLegale').get('dateCreationUniteLegale')
    employee_count = json.loads(res.text).get('uniteLegale').get('trancheEffectifsUniteLegale')
    current_data = json.loads(res.text).get('uniteLegale').get('periodesUniteLegale')[0] 
    company_type = current_data.get('categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale')
    trade = current_data.get('activitePrincipaleUniteLegale')
    return [uid, foundation_date, company_type, trade, employee_count]

df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[],
                   'foundation_date': [],
                   'type': [],
                   'trade': [],
                   'employee_count':[]})

for i in Company.index:
    print(i)
    new = get_info(Company.uid[i])
    df.loc[len(df)] = new
```

**What I have attempted so far**

I used the concurrent.futures library to run the function on multiple rows at the same time.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
    rows = Company[:3].index #to avoid looping over millions rows for now
    results = [executor.map(get_info, Company.uid[row]) for row in rows]
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

This returns the following:

```
<generator object _chain_from_iterable_of_lists at 0x030757D0>
<generator object _chain_from_iterable_of_lists at 0x03075920>
<generator object _chain_from_iterable_of_lists at 0x03075DF0>
```

I then apply `list(result)`

**The issue**

I was expecting to get the list get_info() returns in these generator objects but I am getting this error instead:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-09db72840c98> in <module>
      4         results = [executor.map(get_info, Lots.Siren[row]) for row in rows]
      5     for result in results:
----> 6         for item in result:
      7             print(item)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists(iterable)
    482     careful not to keep references to yielded objects.
    483     """
--> 484     for element in iterable:
    485         element.reverse()
    486         while element:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result_iterator()
    609                     # Careful not to keep a reference to the popped future
    610                     if timeout is None:
--> 611                         yield fs.pop().result()
    612                     else:
    613                         yield fs.pop().result(end_time - time.monotonic())

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    430                 raise CancelledError()
    431             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 432                 return self.__get_result()
    433 
    434             self._condition.wait(timeout)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    386     def __get_result(self):
    387         if self._exception:
--> 388             raise self._exception
    389         else:
    390             return self._result

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

When I try a second time, the objects are empty.

I haven't been able to find a solution online.

**Side notes**

1. I use python 3.6.8 in a local jupyter notebook on a Windows 10 device
2. This is my first post on Stack overflow, I hope I did okay. Please suggest how I could improve my question.

Comment: and where is `get_info`? All problem can be inside this function. It seems it returns some generator.

Comment: I can't run it but maybe you should simply get `list(result)` to get all values from `generator`

Comment: or maybe you have to use `result.get()` or `result.result()` to get value. You should check documentation.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clarify. 
I added `get_info` above, and yes my error is the result of `list(result)`

Comment: `.get()` and `.result()` return an AttributeError

Comment: I tested it on some values and it needs `next(result)` to get value from generator. But all problem is that you use it in wrong way. `map()` is running function with different values WITHOUT using `for`-loop (and without `[ ]`) - like `results = executor.map(get_info, uids)` - and this should gives directly list with all values. Probably for your code could work `results = executor.map(get_info, Company[:3].uid)`

Answer (score 0):

To get value from generator you can use `next()`

```
for result in results:
    print( next(result) )
```

But main problem is that you use `map()` in wrong way.

`map()` gets function and list of values and it runs this function with every value from list separatelly and it returns list with all results - so it replaces `for`-loop and `[]`

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
    results = executor.map(get_info, Company[:3].uid)
```

---

Maybe first you should try `.apply()` because probably it may also use multiprocessing.

```
results = Company[:3].uid.apply(get_info)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example code which I used for tests

```
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures

# --- functions ---

def get_info(uid):
    print(f'uid: {uid}')
    return [uid, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# --- main ---

Company = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]})

# --- version 1 ---

print('\n--- version 1 ---\n')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'uid':[],
    'foundation_date': [],
    'type': [],
    'trade': [],
    'employee_count':[]
})
                      
for i in Company[:3].uid:
    result = get_info(i)
    print(result)
    df.loc[len(df)] = result
    
print('--- df ---')

print(df)    

# --- version 2 ---

print('\n--- version 2 ---\n')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'uid':[],
    'foundation_date': [],
    'type': [],
    'trade': [],
    'employee_count':[]
})

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
    results = executor.map(get_info, Company[:3].uid)

results = list(results)  # map gives generator and it needs `list()`
                         # to get all values and use it many times

for result in results:
    print(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['uid', 'foundation_date', 'type', 'trade', 'employee_count'])

print('--- df ---')

print(df)

# --- version 3 ---

print('\n--- version 3 ---\n')

results = Company[:3].uid.apply(get_info)
print(results)

df = pd.DataFrame(results.to_list(), columns=['uid', 'foundation_date', 'type', 'trade', 'employee_count'])

print('--- df ---')

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge.
Version 2 still gives me a 'BrokenProcessPool' error.
Version 3 works and I will need to test if it is quicker than my loop.

Comment: Version 1 and 3 have the same performance - 6.8 seconds for ten rows.

Comment: see documentation for [BrokenProcessPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool). Maybe one of your `requests` had problem and this makes problem - maybe you have to run code in `try/except`

Comment: I did the `try/except` yesterday as I decided to go forward with the loop for now (there were indeed a few 404 returned). But there should be something else because I still have this `BrokenProcessPool` issue that I need to investigate further. Could be Jupyter, my version of python, or windows maybe. I'll try a couple of things tomorrow. Thank you for the link to the documentation, I'll read that first.

Comment: I have no idea what can be the problem. It doesn't show any details about problem so it hard to say what really makes problem.